# Display corrupt on boot 17.10

Tags: boot, graphics, lubuntu, 17.10

I have been using Lubuntu on my netbook for a while without any problems, but I have just upgraded to 17.10 and now it will not boot properly.  I think that the display driver is problematic for some reason as I have used GRUB to load recovery mode and it works fine.  I have tried dpkg and fsck but they have not made any difference.  I cannot post a screenshot as I am a new user, but after the normal boot cycle, the right hand 20% of the screen is more or less OK and the rest of it is black with corrupted text.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

BB

Comment: You can post a link to a imgur file so people may understand better.

Comment: Encountering the exact same issue

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/Q5lJJTsr.png